# Can the loft of a synthetic bag stored for years be restored?

Tags: sleeping-bags

I recently found the hollofil mummy bag I used in my teens, about 30 years ago. At the time it was quite a warm bag, only usable when it was very cold out.  It's been stored "randomly stuffed" into a stuff sack for all that time, in another bag in a garage (so protected from dirt, direct moisture, and the worst of temperature extremes).

There are answers for [restoring a down sleeping bag](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/15657/down-sleeping-bag-stored-in-sack-for-years) and advice on restoring loft to synthetic and down bags stored for shorter periods, but is it feasible to restore the loft on this bag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will a down sleeping bag recover 100% after being squeezed if it's not for a long time?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/7118/will-a-down-sleeping-bag-recover-100-after-being-squeezed-if-its-not-for-a-lon)

Comment: Regarding the possible dupe Synthetic != down

Answer (score 2):

One thing worth a try is if you have a tumble drier (clothes drier) that will do cold or at least cool. The last 10-20 minutes on the timer is often cold.